# Autopopulate values in database MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

My HTML CODE

```
<form  action="add.jsp" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Order ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="Order_ID"  class="form-con">
        <label>Order Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="Order_Date"  class="form-con">
        <label>Customer Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Customer_Name" class="form-con">
        <label>Customer Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="Customer_ID"  class="form-con">
        <label>Order Amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" id="add1" class="form-con">
        <label>Notes</label>
        <input type="text" name="Notes"  class="form-con">
    </div>
</form>
```

MY DATABASE:

```
Field            Type           Collation        Null    Key     Default    
---------------  -------------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------
Order_ID         int            (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)                     
Customer_Name    varchar(100)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)                      
Customer_ID      int            (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                      
Order_Amount     int            (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                     
Approval_Status  varchar(100)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)                     
Approved_By      varchar(100)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)                     
Notes            varchar(1000)  utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)                     
Order_Date       datetime       (NULL)           YES             (NULL)
```

My query is that: If I add my order amount which is less than 10000 it will autopopulate Approved By field with "David Lee" name. How to acheive this functionality?

My JSP CODE:

```
<%Connection connection = null;
   Statement statement = null;
   ResultSet resultSet = null;
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   String o=request.getParameter("Order_ID");
   String c=request.getParameter("Customer_Name");
   String c2=request.getParameter("Customer_ID");
   String o2=request.getParameter("Order_Amount");
   String n=request.getParameter("Notes");
   String o3= request.getParameter("Order_Date"); 
   java.util.Date o3_1= format.parse(o3);
   String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/winter_internship";
   PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
   int updateQuery = 0;
   if(o!=null && c!=null && c2!=null && o2!=null && n!=null && o3!=null){
        if(o!="" && c!="" && c2!="" && o2!="" && n!="" && o3!="") {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "misspooh2068");
                String queryString = "insert into order_details
                                (Order_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_ID,
                                Order_Amount,Notes,Order_Date) 
                                values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
                pstatement.setString(1, o);
                pstatement.setString(2, c);
                pstatement.setString(3, c2);
                pstatement.setString(4, o2);
                pstatement.setString(5, n);
                java.sql.Date dateJoin= new java.sql.Date(o3_1.getTime());  
                pstatement.setDate(6, dateJoin);  
                updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
                if (updateQuery != 0) { %>
      <% response.sendRedirect("dashboard_hrc.jsp?page=1"); %> 
      <%}} 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
    finally {
        pstatement.close();connection.close();
    }}}%>
```

This is my JSP Code, I want to auto-populate my database column of Approved By whenever a User enters an order amount less than 10000

If the order amount entered is <=10,000, the approval status for a new order will be auto-populated as Approved and Approved By column will display David Lee.

If the order amount entered is >10,000 and <=50,000, the approval status for a new order will be auto-populated as Awaiting Approval and Approved By column will be blank.

If the order amount entered is >50,000, the approval status for a new order will be auto-populated as Awaiting Approval and Approved By column will be blank

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: :)  I am new to StackOverflow cheers :)

Comment: Looks like the Approval Status is the same for `>10,000 and <= 50,000` and `>50,000`

Comment: Are you expecting to do the Approval Status from the JSP Code or are you asking how to make the database do it for you automatically